# DynamoDB Read Units counting

Tags: .net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I've got this table in DynamoDB
ID - is partitionKey.

ID, LockKey, BigDataField

And i've got this piece of code.

```
Table table = Table.LoadTable("blablabla");
GetItemOperationConfig config = new GetItemOperationConfig()
{
     AttributesToGet = new List<string>() { "Id", "LockKey" },
     ConsistentRead = true
};
Document doc = await table.GetItemAsync(Id, config);
```

In this case, how would read units count? For all attributes on that item, or only for attirbutes i wonna get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering out attributes will not effect the total read capacity units consumed.

As stated in the [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html): "DynamoDB calculates the number of read capacity units consumed based on item size, not on the amount of data that is returned to an application. **For this reason, the number of capacity units consumed will be the same whether you request all of the attributes (the default behavior) or just some of them (using a projection expression)**. The number will also be the same whether or not you use a filter expression. "